# How to get the current, "real", background image size, when background-size is cover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might have been asked before and I tried the answer given in this thread: [How to get dimensions for a background image when background-size is set to contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160499/how-to-get-dimensions-for-a-background-image-when-background-size-is-set-to-cont)

But in this case, the `background-size` is set to `cover`, instead of `contain`.

The background size is originally `1920x1080`. I have a div-element which basically always scales its width and height to 100%, meanwhile the background-image if the said div is set to cover.

1920 / 1080 gives us a ratio of about 1.7, so whenever the browser widow is scaled like so that the div's width/height ration is over or under 1.7 aka. not in the correct ratio - things break. So I need a way to calculate what is the size of the background image to correctly set things up.

Edit: Here is an example jsfiddle of the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/35pbovmz/

If you resize the result area, you can see that the result area itself has some width and height, say 400x600. However, this 400 width and 600 height is incorrect for my calculations. I need to know what the size of the background image is. Notice how the background keeps its ratio by basically leaving some of the image out.

The result area width and height are only correct when the result area width/height is exactly the ratio of the background image, which is about 1.7 in this case.

Edit 2: This is now almost working: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/35pbovmz/

Comment: Do you need the div to stay in ratio, if so what's inside the div?  Can we see some code

Comment: Would help a lot if you can provide a code example with the current "not-wanted"-state

Comment: I edited my question with a jsfiddle example and an extra explanation as to what width and height values I need to get.

Comment: If your div is empty and you want to keep aspect ratio then you can use the [padding top trick](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/) - https://jsfiddle.net/35pbovmz/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Here is a nice jsfiddle visualization, where we calculate the container size and the actual background image size separately.

You can resize the image container (red border) by dragging it from the bottom right corner and see how the container size changes separately from the actual background size: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/o76k5jbx/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var fullhdWidth = 1920;
    var fullhdHeight = 1080;
    var fullhdRatio = fullhdWidth / fullhdHeight; // About 1.7

    $('#wrapper').resize(function()
    {
        var containerWidth = $(this).width();
        var containerHeight = $(this).height();
        var containerRatio = containerWidth / containerHeight;
        var realWidth = null;
        var realHeight = null;

        console.log(containerWidth, containerHeight, containerRatio);

        if(containerRatio > fullhdRatio)
        {
            realWidth = containerWidth;
            realHeight = containerWidth/fullhdRatio;
        }
        else
        {
            realWidth = containerHeight*fullhdRatio;
            realHeight = containerHeight;
        }   
    });
});
```

Note: I am using [this](https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize) small library to detect size changes on the container div element, as jQuery's resize handler can only be bound to window object.

Answer (score 1):

I was solving a very specific problem. I had a background image with `background-size: cover` and over that another element with clipping mask that was applying a `filter: invert()` effect.

Everything was responsive and I needed to maintain the position and size of the background on the `.centered` element in sync with the main background.

[image]

```
html {
  background: #000 url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;

  overflow: hidden;

  --w: 1920; // this is the size of my background
  --h: 1080;
}

.centered {
  background-image: url(bg.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: calc(max(calc(100vh / var(--h)), calc(100vw / var(--w))) * var(--w));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  filter: invert(100%)
}
```

Basically, what this does

```
max(calc(100vh / var(--h)), calc(100vw / var(--w)))
```

is that it calculates the size ratio of the *cover* image above its native size:

`calc(100vh / var(--h))` calculates how much is the viewport higher *(eg. 0.8)*
`calc(100vw / var(--w))` calculates how much is the viewport wider *(eg. 1.2)*

Then, whichever of those values is larger, this is how much larger the image MUST be to cover whole viewport.

After that, you simply take the `ratio`, multiply by `width` and you get the current "real" size. You can also get "real" `height` by multiplying it with the `ratio`.

Comment: more advanced live example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285134/whats-the-math-behind-csss-background-sizecover/66660844#66660844